# Tilt switch for 50 amp circuit on ATV winch

Tags: switches

I am using a 12 Vdc, 50 amp motor (ATV Winch) and need a tilt switch in the momentary switch circuit to only allow activation when in certain (horizontal) position.  Any ideas as to where to get on?  The momentary circuit is protected with 10 amp inline fuse, so would the tilt switch only need to be rated at 10 amps?

Answer (score 2):

The ATV winch motor should be on a solenoid and the momentary switch controls the solenoid. The tilt switch will only need to be rated high enough to handle the solenoid coil current, which should only be a couple of amps. If you get a tilt switch rated the same as the 10 amp fuse you should be safe.